# Windows cmd one-liner that finds the default gateway and pings it

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd.exe

Want to create a one-liner to:

1. Obtain an address via DHCP
2. Retrieve the default gateway
3. Ping the default gateway

I am partially there. I do the DHCP renewal and am able to extract the gateway by doing the following

```
> ipconfig /renew * > nul & ipconfig | findstr "Default Gateway" | findstr /o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

I then perform the `ping`. I would rather do it all in one line. However, I cannot figure out how to extract *just* the gateway from this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question so quickly but I think I got it:

```
> FOR /F "tokens=13" %x IN ('"ipconfig /renew * > nul & ipconfig | findstr "Default Gateway" | findstr "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*""') DO ping -t %x
```

Leaving open. Maybe someone knows a more elegant way?